# OpenApi 3.0 oneOf or allOf

Tags: inheritance, openapi

I have been searching and don't find many examples or clear explanation about when to use `allOf` or `oneOf` in OpenApi 3.0.
What is the difference between the use of `allOf` with discriminator or `oneOf`?

My use-case is the following:
a device can't be created if no deviceType are defined. You should be able to create only "mobile device"/"pin device"/"beacon device" which contains the properties depending on their type and also the deviceId and name from the protocol.

For now I have implemented the `allOf` version, and it is working. But I wonder if it is exactly what I want.

```yaml
      Device:
        type: object
        required:
          - id
          - name
          - deviceType
        discriminator: deviceType
        properties:
          deviceId:
            type: string
            description: The id (UUID) of the device
            readOnly: true
          name:
            type: string
            description: The name of the device
          deviceType:
            type: string
            description: The type of the device
            enum:
              - MobileDevice
              - PinDevice
              - BeaconDevice
      mobileDevice:
        allOf:
          - $ref: '#/definitions/Device'
          - required:
              - platform
              - deviceToken
              - location
            properties:
              platform:
                type: string
                description: |
                  The platform of the device, this can be any string
                  representing the platform type, for instance 'iOS'
              deviceToken:
                type: string
                description: |
                  The deviceToken is the device push notification token
                  given to this device by the OS, either iOS or Android for
                  identifying the device with push notification
                  services.
              location:
                "$ref": "#/definitions/Location"
      pinDevice:
        allOf:
          - $ref: '#/definitions/Device'
          - required:
              - location
            properties:
              location:
                "$ref": "#/definitions/Location"
      beaconDevice:
        allOf:
            - $ref: '#/definitions/Device'
            - required:
                - uuid
                - major
                - minor
              properties:
                uuid:
                  type: string
                  description: |
                    The UUID of the beacon, the purpose is to distinguish iBeacons
                    in your network, from all other beacons in
                    networks outside your control.
                major:
                  type: integer
                  description: |
                    Major values are intended to identify and
                    distinguish a group
                  format: int32
                  minimum: 0
                  exclusiveMinimum: false
                  maximum: 65535
                  exclusiveMaximum: false
                minor:
                  type: integer
                  description: |
                    Minor values are intended to identify and
                    distinguish an individual
                  format: int32
                  minimum: 0
                  exclusiveMinimum: false
                  maximum: 65535
                  exclusiveMaximum: false
```

I want to achieve that I shouldn't be able to initialize a device without specifying a type and if it has a specific type it needs to have all the required properties.

Comment: Welcome to [so], when posting here adhere to "There's no chit-chat." as specified in the [tour]: ask direct questions about programming, and not if someone is could explaining something to you (that is not a programming related question at all). Also there should be no thanks, or announcements of appreciation. Please review the changes that I made by clicking the "edited ... ago' link.

Comment: Hey thank you Anthon I am kind of new and will take a look in the tour.